# Boost build show default toolset and version

Tags: c++, boost, bjam, b2

Is there anyway to have boost build (bjam/b2) show the default toolset and version that it will use?

Without explicitly specifying a toolset, there is some way it settles on a toolset and version such as gcc-4.8 or darwin-4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

One possible way could be putting something like this in a jamfile:

```
import notfile ;
import property-set ;

notfile print_toolset : @print_toolset_version ;

rule print_toolset_version ( t : : properties * )
{
    local ps = [ property-set.create $(properties) ] ;
    local toolset = [ $(ps).get <toolset> ] ;
    echo Toolset is $(toolset) ;
    local version = [ $(ps).get <toolset-$(toolset):version> ] ;
    echo Toolset version is $(version) ;
}
```

Comment: I get this error for `property-set`: `(builtin): in property-set.create
ERROR: rule "errors.error" unknown in module "property-set".`

Comment: Which version of Boost.Build are you using? Are the versions inconsistent between `b2` and Boost.Build?